# AngularJS expand collapse number link to list of people, collapse back to number

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want to implement the following scenario like linkedin does:

Let's assume I make a comment and there are people whom will like my comment:

```
Comment blah blah blah

You, Jane Jackson and 5 more like this
```

When you click `5 more` it will show the full list of people:

```
You, Jane Jackson, Jack Black, Jeny Jack, Bill Gates, Steve Mobs and Steve Jobless like this show less...
```

Where `show less` is an actual link that once clicked it will colapse the list to the format:

```
You, Jane Jackson and 5 more like this
```

Assuming I have all the data into a model retrived from a service:

```
$scope.Model = [{
  UserId: '',
  FirstName: '',
  LastName: ''
}];
```

Where the userid is used to format the actual url to the user profile ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a start:

JS:

```
$scope.limitToNumber = 2;
```

HTML:

```
<span ng-repeat="person in Model | limitTo: limitToNumber ">
     {{person.FirstName}} {{ person.LastName }}
<span>
<span ng-if="Model.length > 2">
    <span> and {{Model.length -2}} people liked this <!-- use ng-pluralize here for singular/plural -->
    <span ng-if="limitToNumber == 2" ng-click="limitToNumber=10000000">Show More </span>
    <span ng-if="limitToNumber != 2" ng-click="limitToNumber=2">Show Less </span>
</span>
```